# Binding mistakenly deleted in IIS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis

Sharepoint 2016, our https site binding 32844 was mistakenly deleted!! Any way to simply put it back? Note: There was no certificate associated with that binding, I don't know how it was originally created without one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
New-WebBinding -Name 'SharePoint Web Services' -Protocol https -Port 32844 -IPAddress *
```